# can i use handlers to execute AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handle

In my App i am using AsynchTask to show a busy indicator wjile i am trying to connect to the server. when the App oes into onPause(), i cancel the AsynchTask
as shown in the below posted code. and when the App goes into onResume from onPause, when i try to connec to the server i expect the AsynchTask to be executedbusy
to show busy indicator, but what happens is, the AsynchTask executes and show the bsy indicator but after that the App crash. this behaviour occures only when 
i try to connect to the server when i come from onPause (onPause-> onResume).

so according to the logCat output and as far i i understood it, i am thinking of usig handlers when i am trying to cancel the AsynchTask
please let me know how to solve this issue.

and I aways receive the following LogCat:

```
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): Process: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02, PID: 26111
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ClientHandle
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.getConnection(MqttService.java:552)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.connect(MqttService.java:318)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.doConnect(MqttAndroidClient.java:427)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.access$2(MqttAndroidClient.java:417)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$1.run(MqttAndroidClient.java:395)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and some times te following:

```
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-2
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): Process: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02, PID: 26111
03-09 16:51:27.024: E/AndroidRuntime(26111): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ClientHandle
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.getConnection(MqttService.java:552)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.connect(MqttService.java:318)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.doConnect(MqttAndroidClient.java:427)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.access$2(MqttAndroidClient.java:417)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$1.run(MqttAndroidClient.java:395)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-09 17:08:57.023: E/AndroidRuntime(26667):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Code**:

```
private void cancelAsynchTask() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "@cancelAsynchTask().");

    if (this.MQTTAsynch != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "asynchTask object was initilised");

        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask has not started yet.");
            boolean cancelledSuccessully = this.MQTTAsynch.cancel(true);
            if (cancelledSuccessully) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask is cancelled successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask failed to cancell");
            }
        }

        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask still running doing work in the backgroung thread, and it will be intrrupted");
            boolean cancelledSuccessully = this.MQTTAsynch.cancel(true);
            if (cancelledSuccessully) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask is cancelled successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask failed to cancell");
            }
        }
        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask has finished its work.");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "asynchTask object was not initilised. this.MQTTAsynch == null");
    }
}
```

**doInBackGround**:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "@MQTTAsynchTask(): doInBackground().");
        do {
            try {
                this.MQTTAndroidClient.connect(this.opts, this.context, synchCONNCallBack);
            } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.totalTimeOut += MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT;

        } while ( (!this.isCancelled()) && (this.MQTTAndroidClient != null) && (!isConnectCalled) && (!this.MQTTAndroidClient.isConnected()) && (this.totalTimeOut <= (10 * MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT)) );

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to say this: **ASYNC** not Asynch...

Answer (score 1):

Don't unnecessarily complicate things for yourself. The `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask` are executed on the main UI thread. This means you can make any change to your UI, including displaying any dialogs. Override these methods and modify your UI likewise. Only the `doInBackground()` is executed in background and any changes to the UI, from this method, wold require you to use a `Handler`.

Comment: fine, but why i am receiving the above posted logcat when i try to execute the AsynchTask while i left onPause and inside onResume. in other words, i i am in onPause ten in onResuem, and try to execute it, i receive the above logCats

Comment: Go over your logcat and read the stacktrace. There will be a "Caused By" section.

Comment: Because you're unnecesarily using Handlers?

Comment: i am not using handlers...i posted this ques. to seek opinions re using handlers or not...but till now ia mnot using it and i receive the above logcats errors

Comment: What is in the "Caused By" section? What line does it point to? :)

Comment: @LittleChild what is "Caused by section"??

Comment: @LittleChild please see the logCat section, i updated it

Comment: @rmaik Your problem is at `MqttService.java:552`